# Python Flask Web API [Heroku]: It runs locally but shows Application Error when deployed

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have done a search on Stack Overflow looking for an answer that will help me to get my Web API working, but somehow, I still don't have the answer that I need. I have followed all the necessarily steps up till the moment I can deploy the project to Heroku (through GitHub), and it shows no build error. Procfile is already included, so is my requirements.txt. Please see below:

**Project Directory:**

```
app-directory/
  |-main-api.py
  |-Procfile
  |-requirements.txt
  |-..other files..
```

**Procfile (Updated):**

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 main-api:app
```

**requirements.txt:**

- Flask
- PyMongo
- Gunicorn

In main-api.py...

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_index():
    customers = mongo.db.customers

    output = []

    for c in customers.find():
        output.append({'_id': c['_id'], 'first_name': c['first_name'],
                   'last_name': c['last_name'],
                   'date_of_birth': c['date_of_birth'],
                   'is_online': c['is_online']})

    return jsonify({'results': output})
```

And finally...running the web project in Heroku itself:

Heroku Web - Python-Flask-Error

[image]

Anyone with similar experience or have the right solution to this problem, appreciate if you can share it. Thanks a million folks!

P.S. Sorry that I forgot to add the log from Heroku:

```
2017-04-24T18:22:17.118866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 main-api:app`
2017-04-24T18:22:20.224956+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-24 18:22:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-04-24T18:22:20.225914+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-24 18:22:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (4)
2017-04-24T18:22:20.226111+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-24 18:22:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-04-24T18:22:20.230648+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-24 18:22:20 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2017-04-24T18:22:20.332390+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-24 18:22:20 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2017-04-24T18:23:17.510473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-04-24T18:23:17.510556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-04-24T18:23:17.686086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-24T18:23:17.667150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-04-24T18:23:19.078229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cx-machinelearning.herokuapp.com request_id=1ce56539-862b-4355-ba36-a6453a646890 fwd="101.127.102.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-04-24T18:23:19.971719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cx-machinelearning.herokuapp.com request_id=55d8cad7-3967-466b-b78c-d9e377be8cbc fwd="101.127.102.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have checked to ensure that debug=True has been set in the **main** section of main_api.py.

Comment: did you try checking the logs? you can check the logs using `heroku logs` if you use the heroku cli, or directly from the heroku app dashboard if you like having a UI

Comment: I have added the log segment from Heroku's log.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the Heroku load balancer cannot reach your application because it listens on localhost only (IP address `127.0.0.1`). Moreover, Heroku allocates port numbers dynamically and assigns the current value to the `PORT` environment variable.

Try the following Procfile instead:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT main-api:app
```

Comment: Thanks @adam-brytek for the assistance! It works like a charm. Setting this as the answer. I hope someone will benefit from this question.

Comment: You're welcome @ShermanChen but looks like you didn't tick the answer mark in the end :)

Comment: Yeap, it's done. Sorry, its my first time proactively taking part in stackoverflow. Hope to make some contributions of my own in terms of providing answers in other areas.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same error for a week and wasted tens of hours online searching for answers! The heroku official document does no help, thank you so much!

Comment: I have used this same but still facing issue?  any other options guys?

Comment: I am having the same error. The solution mentioned in not solving the issue.

Comment: not working for me too. followed every step as per the **heroku** docs but getting same error _at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"_

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that in my Procfile I wrote:

```
web: gunicorn appname:app
```

where appname is the application name I used in Heroku website, instead of:

```
web: gunicorn MainScriptName:app
```

That means get yourscriptname.py and just copy it without extension, so you get `yourscriptname:app`